# React useState - how to put array of objects into state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state, react-hooks

I've got a React app which I'm pulling data down from a RESTful API. The data in the response is an array of objects. I'm trying to get that information and store it in React state using useState and then render that as a list on the page.

I've faked the API in the link below by assigning some dummy array of objects to `book` and then trying to set that as state but it's not working. Any ideas how to pass it to the state and then display it on the page?

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-sunset-1ejxi

Comment: const [yourArray, setYourArray] = useState([]); and then setYourArray(pass here the response of your request.) and it will update your array (yourArray) then you can iterate by using yourArray.map(item => { console.log(item) } )

Comment: `useEffect(books => {` `useEffect` callback doesn't have any arguments. Change that line to `useEffect(() => {`

Comment: @JS_Dev Please include the code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass `books` as argument in `useEffect` callback. You need to reference books from outside scope

```
  useEffect(() => {
     setBookList(books);
  }, []);
```

In this case it will reference  `books` in component body.

```
  useEffect(() => {
     fetch('some_url).then(res => res.json()).then(books => setBookList(books)); 
  }, []);
```